# Highcharts isn't showing anything using CSV data method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

It doesn't work on all three browsers - IE, Chrome and Firefox.

Here's the source code for my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="jquery-1.10.2.js" ></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="highcharts.js" ></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="exporting.js" ></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="fruits.js" ></script>
</head>


<body>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the source code for what I have in the fruits.js script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Units'
            }
        },
        series: []
    };

    $.get('data.csv', function (data) {
        // Split the lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        // Iterate over the lines and add categories or series
        $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {
            var items = line.split(',');
            // header line containes categories
            if (lineNo == 0) {
                $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo > 0) options.xAxis.categories.push(item);
                });
            }
            // the rest of the lines contain data with their name in the first 
            // position
            else {
                var series = {
                    data: []
                };
                $.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                    if (itemNo == 0) {
                        series.name = item;
                    } else {
                        series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
                    }
                });

                options.series.push(series);
            }

        });

        // Create the chart
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
    });
});
```

So any idea why isn't the chart displays anything at all?  It does works without the CSV data file though

This is what I have in my csv file:

```
Categories,Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas
John,8,4,6,5
Jane,3,4,2,3
Joe,86,76,79,77
Janet,3,16,13,15
```

Comment: How do you check that?  It just displays a blank page

Comment: Depending on the browser it may be different but in general hit F12. This brings up a dev console. One of the items would be console output. It will display errors and such. You can also programmatically write to it in JS with `console.log(<something>)`.

Comment: Yeah it says syntax error which refer to this:  Categories,Apples,Pears,Oranges,Bananas

and this too: [00:21:04.529] uncaught exception: Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16

Comment: So, you need to find out where that error occurs in the code. I can only guess since I do have your full code but it may be that you are not quoting these values in your returned category list? Also, you probably do not need to have `Categories` returned. Can you post up your code that actually creates the `item`?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about lol.  I took it from here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json

Also, it works on IE10, but not on IE11.

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Yes, jsFiddle please.

Comment: Well its strange, because I open your example in IE10/Chrome / IE11 and in all cases, all works properly. http://tinyurl.com/o9uyn3q

Comment: Link's seem to be working fine, but when I launch it locally here it won't shows anything!  Only works in IE10 ;_;